# Kendo UI TreeList - Datasource Binding issue

Tags: kendo-ui

I'll apologize if this is easy, but Google has failed me.

I have a call back that runs once data has been received from a service.  I'm trying to take that data, create a few data sources, and bind them to a few controls.

I've simplified the code down

This works:

```
function onDataLoad (inData) {

    $("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
        resizable: true,
        width: "100%",
        "columns": gridColumns,
        "dataSource": {
            data: inData,
            schema: {
                data: "returnsData"
            }
        }
    });
};
```

However, if I take that data source definition and try to move it out, I get a `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"` error.

```
function onDataLoad (inData) {

    var returnsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: inData,
            schema: {
                data: "returnsData"
            }
        });

    $("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
        resizable: true,
        width: "100%",
        "columns": gridColumns,
        "dataSource": returnsDataSource
    });
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use TreeListDataSource instead of DataSource:

```
var returnsDataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
        data: inData,
        schema: {
            data: "returnsData"
        }
    });
```

See http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/local-data-binding for an example.

Comment: Figured it was easy!  Thanks.